# New domain. htaccess / rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've decided to change my domain to a more brandable. It's a travel website with tips on things to do in different cities around the globe.

Right now each page starts with "city" in the url. 
Examples:

www.olddomain.com/city-new-york

www.olddomain.com/city-london

www.olddomain.com/city-paris

On the new domain each page will start with "tips" instead.
Examples:

www.newdomain.com/tips-new-york

www.newdomain.com/tips-london

www.newdomain.com/tips-paris

What can i write in the htaccess-file to make a 301 redirect from www.olddomain.com/city-xxx to www.newdomain.com/tips-xxx?
Is this even possible or do I have to do it manually for each domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a redirect match:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/city-(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/tips-$1
```

Any query strings will automatically get appended to the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon! What about the index page and other pages such as the about and contact pages? Do i need to use a separate rewrite for this?

Comment: @AffeAff these are all redirects (e.g. you're telling the browser to go somewhere new) and not rewrites (internally changing the URL within the web server). You can just add another redirect directive **under** the one above: `Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/`